# Do I need a lock if I only have a single reader/writer and it's not timecritical?

Tags: c#, concurrency, locking

I have a program which has a User Interface.

When the user presses a button, the program will load some data and that will take a minute or so, so naturally the interface would fail to update.

So, instead I'm doing the following - I have a boolean variable called "hasLoaded" which the loading code (working on it's own thread) will set to true when it's done. The interface will check every so often and stop displaying the 'Loading' screen.

The question is - since this is a shared variable, you'd probably want to lock it (or use a reader/writer slim lock or something). The lock would obviously be around just the shared variable ("hasLoaded"). However since:

1. There is only one reader
2. There is only one writer
3. It's okay if the interface reads the 'wrong' value since it's going to check again in a fraction of a second

Do I still need the lock ? To clarify - are there any 'data corruption' caveats or other issues that can happen if both threads try to read it at the same time, or is the 'worst' thing that can happen is that it reads the wrong value once and picks it up correctly next time round?

Comment: A lock would prevent concurrent operations to a resource which is shared across threads. Which resource is shared across threads that you think you might need to lock?

Comment: The variable itself. Sorry, thought I made it clear. I'll review my question real quick

Comment: just use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx) and wait for it to fire its RunWorkerCompleted event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a data type that is less than or equal to the word size of the CPU architecture you would have little cause for worry in regards to whether there will be data corruption issues. Writes and reads will be atomic.

That is not the issue though. The issue is that in some circumstances the reader of that flag may never see it change to a `true` value. This is actually pretty easy to demonstrate with the following code. You will need to compile it with the Release configuration and run it without the debugger attached. You may observe that the program never ends effectively demonstrating the bug.

```
// * Must be compiled as RELEASE and ran outside of a debugger.
class Program
{   
    // Decorate with volatile to change the behavior.
    static bool stop = false;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("thread begin");
            bool toggle = false;
            while (!stop)
            {
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("thread end");
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        stop = true;
        Console.WriteLine("stop = true");
        Console.WriteLine("waiting...");

        // The Join call should return almost immediately.
        // With volatile it DOES.
        // Without volatile it does NOT.
        t.Join();         
    }
}
```

In your specific case this may actually be moot though. The reason being that the writer is the background thread and the reader is the UI thread. That is crucial here because a memory barrier will guarantee that the write gets committed when the background thread ends which is probably immediately after `hasLoad` gets set to `true`. On the UI thread side of things the message pump itself is likely injecting a memory barrier unbeknownst to you. So every time you check the value of `hasLoaded` (presumably with a timer of some kind) you will probably get the latest value.

Regardless, if it works without a lock or using `volatile` it is doing so only by accident. Do yourself a favor and take the appropriate safeguards and just take the lock.

Better yet, use a `Task` in conjunction with the new `async` and `await` keywords. If done correctly this can be accomplished without even needing the `hasLoaded` flag and it will look more elegant as well.

Comment: That made an interesting read. Pretty much what I wanted as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your boolean as volatile.

As described on MSDN :

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by
>   multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are
>   declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that
>   assume access by a single thread. This ensures that the most
>   up-to-date value is present in the field at all times.

If you do not declare it as volatile, the compiler might optimize your code in such a way that the update of the flag will never be visible for the other thread.

Comment: It's called 'stale data' and though it's unlikely (it depends on the actual code etc) you are formally right.

Answer (score -1):

You would not need to lock the boolean value for your example, but if you may want to make a code comment to indicate why you chose not to lock, since you might revisit this code and have different expectations about 'dirty' reads of the shared boolean value.

Comment: This is false.  The operation is not in fact safe.